# Offline download and storage of Video for Ionic App

Tags: android, ios, video, ionic-framework, local-storage

I am newbie to Ionic App Development.

I have a requirement where I need to **download videos** from my app and **store them within** the app so that the videos are not accessible from the folders, but can be **viewed only from the App**.

example: *The way youtube offline storage works for download/storage and viewing of the videos.*

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this in Xamarin. You have to create your file in app special folder under ur application path/config. User cannot view that file. After creating file you have to download video bytes by bytes and write into your file. Below is the code that i used to create file and download and read to that file in xamarin.

```
var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var filename = Path.Combine(path, ad.adid + ".mp4");
System.Uri url = new System.Uri(ad.video_url);
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024;

using (var outputFileStream = File.Create(filename))
{


    try
    {
        var req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = req.GetResponse())
        {

         using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                do
                {

                bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                outputFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);


                } while (bytesRead > 0);



                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        File.Delete(filename);
                        StopSelf();
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        File.Delete(filename);
        StopSelf();
        return;
    }
}
```

}

P.S : As i mentioned this is xmarin c sharp code. This will not work on android but idea remained the same. You can easily convert this code to java.